# MySQL commands inside Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have the following docker compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_root_pw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=some_db
      - MYSQL_USER=db_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pw
    ports:
      - 8306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql/some_db
```

I am accessing the container with the command:

```
docker-compose exec db /bin/sh
```

Which drops me at the shell as expected. However, I am unable to access mysql with the information from the docker-compose file.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Prompts for the password, then rejects for bad username or password. I have tried with both root and user. Is there a way I can troubleshoot what is happening with user creation?

NOTE: intentionally older version of MySQL.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with given docker-compose. The only thing I changed is removing `volumes` section.

Comment: you're right - that folder was empty, but I did need it for persistence. Like you, if I remove the volume I can access the database without issue. If you want to post this as the answer I'll accept it. thanks!

Comment: I have just tested with sample volume mount and it still works. So there has to be something else that causes your problem.